# Calculating the average in Pig Latin

Tags: java, apache-pig

Consider a data file:

```
4, 8, 2
5, 2, 5
3, 1, 7
```

I want to calculate the average of every column. What's the easiest way to do this?
 What if I have 20 columns, is there a loop, so that I don't have to calculate it for every column manually?

Comment: Igpay Latinay is not a very good ogrammingPay anguageLay.

Comment: @HotLicks: As you can see here: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html this is the official name. How would you call the programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(a,b,c);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE AVG(TOBAG(*));
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(4.666666666666667)
(4.0)
(3.6666666666666665)
```

**Update: Avg of each columns**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(a,b,c);
B = GROUP A ALL;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE AVG(A.a),AVG(A.b),AVG(A.c);
DUMP C;
```

**Output:**

```
(4.0,3.6666666666666665,4.666666666666667)
```

Comment: This gives me the average of the lines: (4+8+2)/3. I need the average of the columns: (4+5+3)/3.